# chkconfig --list | grep --quiet "jetty" won't work in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

chkconfig --list | grep --quiet "jetty" work in command line or script without "set -o pipefail", not work with "set -o pipefail" in script. why?

the original script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -o pipefail

echo -e "checking jetty is installed ...\n"
echo -e "start...\n"
chkconfig --list | grep --quiet "jetty"
echo $?
echo -e "end...\n"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

after tracing the execution:
it outputs "Start...", the script exit after running "chkconfig --list | grep --quiet jetty", so "echo $?" and latter tracing output nothing. just do not know why the pipe failed. if i comment "set -o pipefail", then the script work just fine.

environment:

1)CentOS release 6.6 (Final) 64bit

2)GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

3)GNU grep 2.6.3

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in a script? Are you running the script with `bash` or `/bin/sh`?

Comment: plus, chkconfig --list output does contain "jetty"

Comment: hi Etan, i just run it in /bin/sh and "./test.sh" form, still fail. As you asked "What do you mean it doesn't work in a script?" : i put "echo $?" after "chkconfig --list | grep --quiet jetty" to trace it, but it will stop there without going to "echo $?"

Comment: What's the `#!` line of the script? `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: And you still haven't told us what "failing" is here. Does it explode? Does it kill a kitten? Does it not find the output? What?

Comment: the #! line is "#!/usr/bin/env bash"

Comment: Show us the script (or snippet of script) and **tell us what failing means**.

Answer (score 0):

With `set -e`, the script will exit if `grep` doesn't find a match -- that's what `set -e` does, it converts every error into a fatal one. You need to wrap any command which can fail in an error-handling conditional. Fortunately, this is how you should have written this particular script even without `set -e`, too.

```
if chkconfig --list | grep --quiet 'jetty'; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: hi tripleee: i tried your way with "set -e", it worked, thank you. In my original script, if i remove "--quiet" option, the script works fine. Do not know why '--quiet" cause this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `set -e`, because it will let the script to exit if hit any error command.
Also it seems that the `echo $?` after `chkconfig --list | grep --quiet "jetty"` has changed your "$?" value.

So you can write it like this:

```
if chkconfig --list | grep --quiet "ssh"
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: Use either `[` or `grep` but not both.